# Can I do a foreach Column with linq in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, foreach

I am using the telerik ASP.NET MVC Grid template and currently have several check boxes (one for each column in a table).  This way the user can select which columns they want to be displayed in the grid.

Instead of manually writing out each checkbox on the view, can I use a foreach loop to have each check box generated on the view for me?

I'm looking to replace something like this:

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("SomeColumnID", false, "Something")%><label for="SomeColumnID">Some Label</label>
// . . . over and over again for each column
```

With something like this:

```
<%foreach (ColumnInGivenDB)
{%>
   <%= Html.CheckBox(SomeColumnIDVariable, false, SomeOtherVariable)%><label for=SomeColumnIDVariable>Some Label</label>
<%}%>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're almost there, but missing binding to the `Model` or one if its properties part.

You mean something like the following?

As an example I am binding to a simple object with UserName property

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%=Html.CheckBox(item.UserId, (IsChecked logic here)) %>
            <label for="<%=item.UserId%>"><%=item.UserName %></label>
        </td>

    </tr>

<% } %>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I found that one of the columns is named title and so the label does not work on that one, I guess, because title is part of an HTML tag.  I know I can put an if item.UserID == "title", but in the long run, I'll have more control over what's displayed by doing each check box manually rather than with a foreach.  Thank you for the help :)